# Create a Function for Customized Tabular Representation

Tags: function, grid, wolfram-mathematica, tabular

I use the code below get an overview of parts of my data.

- What would be the best way to make a function out of the below code ?
- It would take a dataList as well as some graphical options (such as colors) as arguments and return a customized tabular representation as shown below.

  ```
  overviewtheData=Text@Grid[{Map[Rotate[Text[#],
  90Degree]&,data[[1]]]}~Join~data[[2;;]],
  Background->{{{{White,Pink}},{1->White}}},
  Dividers->{All,{1->True,2->True,0->True}},
  ItemSize->{1->5,Automatic},
  Alignment->Top,
  Frame->True,
  FrameStyle->Thickness[2],
  ItemStyle->{Automatic,Automatic,{{1,1},
  {1,Length@data[[1]]}}->Directive[FontSize->15,Black,Bold]}]
  ```

---

[image]

Comment: I edited your code because horizontal slidebars are awful

Comment: I wouldn't describe the above as a _graphical_ representation. It's a _tabular_ representation...   I find the question a bit unclear, could you try to rephrase it?

Comment: @Sjoerd, hope it is better now

Comment: It would be better to correct the title too: the question is not related to `Graphics` in *Mathematica*'s sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Belisarius gave the basic method.  I shall introduce an advanced method, because you seem eager to learn.

First let me say that I saw what I believed were simplifications to your code, and I made them, hopefully not in error.

I will use this sample data in illustrations below:

```
data = Prepend[
         RandomInteger[99, {5, 12}], 
         DateString[{1, #}, "MonthName"] & /@ Range@12
       ];
```

---

### Goals

1. Since the main function used is `Grid` it makes sense to allow passing options to it.
2. You have a series of options that define your table.  I want to be able to conveniently change these.
3. I want the possibility of custom options not understood by `Grid`.

---

### Implementation

#### Goal #1

An argument pattern `opts:OptionsPattern[]` is added, which matches any sequence of `Option -> Setting` arguments, and names it `opts`. (See: [OptionsPattern](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OptionsPattern.html) for more.)  Then, `opts` is inserted into the basic function before the other options for `Grid`.  This allows any explicitly given options to override the defaults, or new ones to be given.

```
customTabular[data_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Grid[MapAt[Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ # &, data, 1],
   opts,
   Background -> {{{White, Pink}}},
   Dividers -> {All, {2 -> True}},
   ItemSize -> {1 -> 5},
   Alignment -> {Center, {1 -> Top}},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameStyle -> Thickness[2],
   ItemStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 15, Black, Bold]
  ] // Text
```

Examples:

```
customTabular[data]
```

[image]

```
customTabular[data, Background -> LightBlue]
```

[image]

#### Goal #2

The options that define your tabular format can be separated from the function body.  This will allow them to be conveniently changed or referenced.  I start by clearing the previous definition with `ClearAll`.  Then I set default [`Options`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Options.html) for `customTabular`:

```
ClearAll[customTabular]

Options[customTabular] =
  {Background -> {{{White, Pink}}},
   Dividers -> {All, {2 -> True}},
   ItemSize -> {1 -> 5},
   Alignment -> {Center, {1 -> Top}},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameStyle -> Thickness[2],
   ItemStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 15, Black, Bold]};
```

Now the function proper.  Here `Options@customTabular` gets the rules given above.

```
customTabular[data_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Grid[MapAt[Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ # &, data, 1],
   opts, 
   Sequence @@ Options@customTabular
 ] // Text
```

Now you can easily change the defaults with [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetOptions.html).  Example:

```
SetOptions[customTabular, 
  Background -> {{{LightMagenta, LightOrange}}}
];

customTabular[data]
```

[image]

#### Goal #3

Now I want to add an option that is *not* passed to `Grid`.  I choose `"Rotation"` to change the text rotation of the title row.

Again I clear the prior definition and the default options.   Notice the inclusion of `"Rotation" -> 90 Degree` in the list.

```
ClearAll[customTabular]

Options[customTabular] =
  {Background -> {{{White, Pink}}},
   Dividers -> {All, {2 -> True}},
   ItemSize -> {1 -> 5},
   Alignment -> {Center, {1 -> Top}},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameStyle -> Thickness[2],
   ItemStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 15, Black, Bold],
   "Rotation" -> 90 Degree};
```

Now I need a way to use this new option, and I need a way to keep this option from being sent to `Grid`:

- I access the option with [`OptionValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OptionValue.html) which will give the default if none is explicitly given.
- I pass only valid `Grid` options by using [`FilterRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FilterRules.html).

I first join any explicit options to the front of the `Options@customTabular` list, again to override defaults.

```
customTabular[data_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Grid[MapAt[Rotate[#, OptionValue["Rotation"]] & /@ # &, data, 1],
   Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts} ~Join~ Options@customTabular, Options@Grid]
 ] // Text
```

Example:

```
SetOptions[customTabular, Background -> {{{LightBrown, LightYellow}}}];

customTabular[data,
  Dividers -> All,
  "Rotation" -> -90 Degree,
  FrameStyle -> {Darker@Red, Thick}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Shows the design process, not just the result. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Nothing much comes to mind. If you *really* want this to be maximally didactic (it is didactic already), you could may be put references / links to the documentation for things like `OptionsPattern` and `FilterRules`, and a few links to some places where options mechanism is discussed.

Comment: @d00b Thanks!  I am learning from Leonid how to give good answers.

Comment: @Leonid, I noticed that for `Grid` my use of `Sequence @@` is superfluous.  Is this true more generally?  `OptionsPattern[]` matches rules in or out of lists; is it safe to assume that most functions accept options given like: `f[1, 2, op1 -> val, op2 -> val, {op3 -> val, op4 -> val}]`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Nope, it is not safe (IMO). The problem is that when you pass options more than once, you may accumulate the depth of the rule list. And since rules at depth more than one in a (nested) list are not interpreted as options, you may run into trouble. And in any case, I would not count on that  - this does not look for me like a good case for saving a few keystrokes. Just my two cents...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Oh, by the way, congrats with the Mathematica silver badge!

Comment: @Leonid, I knew you would have some advice.  I always use `Sequence` in this way, and I suspect for a reason, but I wanted to make sure that reason wasn't antiquated.  Re: the badge, thank you! :D

Answer (score 4):

I'd do it the usual way

```
f[data_, color1_, color2_] := 
 Text@Grid[{Map[Rotate[Text[#], 90 Degree] &, data[[1]]]}~Join~
    data[[2 ;;]], Background -> {{{{color1, color2}}, {1 -> color1}}},
    Dividers -> {All, {1 -> True, 2 -> True, 0 -> True}},
    ItemSize -> {1 -> 5, Automatic}, Alignment -> Top, Frame -> True, 
    FrameStyle -> Thickness[2], 
    ItemStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, {{1, 1}, {1, Length@data[[1]]}} -> 
                               Directive[FontSize -> 15, Black, Bold]}]

f[{{t1, t2, t3}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, LightBlue, Orange]
```

[image]

I am not sure what you are trying to ask for in the last part `such a graph as an output` ...