# Dynamic List Selection within another Dynamic in Mathematica

Tags: dynamic, wolfram-mathematica, tabular

Building up on the solution proposed by Belisarius in ["Manipulate custom Tabular"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333622/manipulate-custom-tabular-representation-in-mathematica).

- Consider the following Function to create custom Tabular representation :

  ```
  DataSampleXX[data_, linesNumber_, columnsList_, color1_, color2_, color3_] :=

  Grid[
  Join[
       {columnsList}, {Map[Rotate[Text[#], 90 Degree] &, 
        data[[1, columnsList]]]}, data[[2 ;; linesNumber, columnsList]]],
  Background  -> {{{{color1, color2}}, {1 -> color3}}},
  Dividers    -> {All, {1 -> True, 2 -> True, 3 -> True, 0 -> True}},
  ItemSize    -> {1 -> Automatic, Automatic},
  Alignment   -> Top,
  Frame       -> True,
  FrameStyle  -> Thickness[2],
  ItemStyle   -> {Automatic, 
  Automatic, {{1, 1}, 
  {1, Length[data]}} -> Directive[FontSize -> 15, Black, Bold]}
  ];
  ```
- And the following data :

  ```
  soData = {{"col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", 
             "col8", "col9", "col10"}, Range[1, 10], Range[11, 20], 
              Range[21, 30], Range[31, 40]}


  With[
       {columnsList = {1, 3},
        data = soData,
        linesNumber = 3,
        color1 = LightBlue,
        color2 = LightRed,
        color3 = LightGray},
        DataSampleXX[data, linesNumber, columnsList, color1, color2, color3]]
  ```

[image: Output]

- I would like to integrate the following Dynamic to feed the `columnsList` argument of the `DataSampleXX` Function.

  ```
  Manipulate[Sort@Join[Sequence @@ {a, b}], 
             Evaluate[Sequence @@ MapThread[{{#1, {}, ""}, #2, 
             ControlType -> TogglerBar} &, {{a, b},
             Partition[Rule @@@ Transpose[{Range[10], soData[[1]]}], 5]}]], 
             ControlPlacement -> Top]
  ```

[image: What I want]

- This should enable me to **dynamically choose the columns** (VS a range of column in my previous question) to display using `DataSampleXX` but I yet can`t figure out how to merge the 2 mechanisms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want to do needs a few tricks.

For example:

```
 Maipulate[ f[ Array[ a, exp], ...], ...]
```

and similar constructs do not work (and is explained in the docs), because the `a[_]` are not explicit in the expression, so making it difficult to have a variable number of controls. The solution I found is:

```
Manipulate[ f[#,...], ... ] & @ Array[a, exp]
```

Other problem is that the construct

```
 Control@( .#. ) &/@ _controls_
```

does not allow per se a two dimensional partition, so we have to use both Control@ syntax options ( Control@ and { ... }), which is not documented.

Other nuisances you can find in the code below.

So:

```
soData = {{"col01", "col02", "col03", "col04", "col05", "col06", 
          "col07", "col08", "col09", "col10"}, 
           Range[1, 10], Range[11, 20], Range[21, 30], Range[31, 40]};
perRow = 5;
colsel = (# -> Graphics[{#, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 15]) &/@ColorData[1, "ColorList"];
s[x_] := Style[x, Black, Bold, 12];
ct = ControlType -> PopupMenu;

Manipulate[
   DataSampleXX[soData, linesNumber, Sort@Join[Sequence @@ #], color1,
                                                               color2, color3], 
   Row[
     {Column[
       {Control@{{linesNumber, 2, s@"Lines"}, 
         Range[2, Length@soData[[All, 1]] - 1], ct}}], 
        Spacer[20], 
     Column[
       {Control@{{color1, colsel[[1, 1]], s@"Color 1"}, colsel, ct},
        Control@{{color2, colsel[[2, 1]], s@"Color 2"}, colsel, ct}, 
        Control@{{color3, colsel[[3, 1]], s@"Color 3"}, colsel, ct}}]}], 
   Evaluate[
    Sequence @@ 
     MapThread[{{#1, {}, ""}, #2, ControlType -> TogglerBar} &, 
        {#, Partition[Rule @@@ Transpose[{Range[10], soData[[1]]}], perRow]}]]] &@ 
Array[a, Length[soData[[1]]]/perRow]
```

[image]

Comment: @Belisarius, it is ! Now, my problem is that I have 100 columns, this is why I separated in group of 5, is there a way to adjust your code to do so ?Also, I once tried to send you an e-mail on the address you provide on your profile without success. And I would like to show you what I came to using some of your solutions !

Comment: @500 let me see if I can come up with something for the hundred cols problems. Re "my email" ... it is working. Sounds silly, but ... Have you replaced the `[dot]` and `[at]` by the corresponding symbols ?

Comment: @Belisarius, just sent you an e-mail in case it goes in your spam box. I hope my code won`t be to ugly to your expert eyes. Many thanks for your attention.

Comment: @Belisarius, thanks a lot it works very well, I am glad it was "tricky" !

Comment: @Belisarius, Thank You, I shall now try to make all the button size equal using your other solution ! Does look tricky as well !